# Simplest way to write to sql server from silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I think that this is a task that would be common enough to have a streamlined framework for its implementation.

But for the past few days I have been going through articles on WCF service that go down to a fundamental and detailed level.

Am i missing something here or do I have to go through a bunch of configuration files and multiple projects to implement this seemingly simple task?

Comment: Also consider Linq to SQL or Entity Framework -- generated classes get marked with the `DataContract` attributes, so they're WCF ready.

Comment: "WCF RIA Services Version 1 Service Pack 2 is compatible with either .NET framework 4 or .NET Framework 4.5, and with either Silverlight 4 or Silverlight 5."

I'm using .NET framework 4 and silverlight 5